# Elastic Uptime Monitors using Heartbeat --Few Monitors are missing in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, heartbeat, elastic-apm

I have the elk setup in a ec2 server.With Beats like metricbeat,filebeat,heartbeat.

I have setup the elastic apm for some applications like jenkins & sonarqube.

Now In uptime I can see only few monitors like sonarqube and jenkins
Other application are missing..

When I see data from yesterday not available in elasticsearch for particular application

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot what is going on is to check if the events from Heartbeat are being collected. The Uptime application only displays events from Heartbeat, and therefore — this is the Beat that you need to check.

First, check the connectivity of Heartbeat and the configured output:

```
metricbeat test output
```

Secondly, check if the events are being generated. You can check this by commenting out your existing output (Likely Elasticsearc/Elastic Cloud) and enabling either the [Console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/console-output.html) output or the [File](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/file-output.html) output. Then start your Metricbeat and check if events are being generated. If they are, then it might be something with the backend side of things; maybe Elasticsearch is rejecting the documents sent and refusing to index them.

Apropos, Elastic is implementing a native **Jenkins** plugin that allows you to observe your CI pipeline using OpenTelemetry compatible backends such as **Elastic APM**. You can learn more about this plugin [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/opentelemetry-plugin).

Comment: I saw your post and the plugin..Looks promising ..Thanks